# Python pip virturalenv: Not uninstalling PACKAGE at PATH1, outside environment PATH2

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, environment

I have a virtualenv in Python 3.5. I installed a bunch of packages with pip, including TFLearn 0.2.1. It had a [bug](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/issues/480) which was preventing the [script](https://github.com/llSourcell/build_a_neural_net_live) that I was trying to run from creating the network. Tried uninstalling it, reinstalling it, nothing. Then, I cloned the TFlearn github repo, rolled back the version, and (still in virtualenv) ran

`pip install -e tflearn`

No avail at fixing my bug. I wanted to go back to 0.2.2 and try another strategy, so I ran

`pip install --upgrade tflearn`

Worked fine. More debugging, decided to run

`pip uninstall tflearn`

and now I get the error:

`Not uninstalling tflearn at /home/user/ve/src/tflearn, outside environment /home/user/ve/ml`

`ve` is a folder in my home directory and `ml` is the name of the venv. Why is it saying it is outside the environment, when it very clearly is installed in the VE (pip freeze) and all commands were in the activated VE? And more importantly, how do I unmangle it?

Comment: I had the same error but I use [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and I have added my local custom lib to virtualenv via [add2virtualenv](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html?highlight=add2virtualenv#add2virtualenv) command (for lib-debugging purposes) and then tried to install this custom lib via pip. Removing local lib path from add2virtualenv list helped.

Comment: @BreadHunter could you be a bit more specific with the steps you took to remove local lib path? I'm not familiar with add2virtualenv. Thanks!

Comment: If you didn't use virtualenvwrapper and its 'add2virtualenv' command then it's very likely that you had different problem than I had. However, if you use virtualenvwrapper you can check if you have any path added simply by calling add2virtualenv (being in activated virtualenv). To remove path: `add2virtualenv -d <path-to-remove> `

Comment: Yeah I don't even have virtualenvwrapper installed, so I am not sure what borked. But I'll keep that in mind the next time something like this crops up (Ended up with just wiping the VE and the install directories and starting fresh)

Answer (score 0):

For me upgrading pip fixed this problem

```
(venv) myusername # pip install --upgrade pip
...
Successfully installed pip-20.3.3

(venv) myusername # pip uninstall <mypackage>
```